# Google map api v3: Adding custom undo/redo function for edited Polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a functionality where in the user can draw a polygon over the Google map. Once the polygon is complete he can edit the same but cannot add a new one. Also once the user clicks on any of the vertices, it deletes that node. Usually when a polygon or any shape that is edited, it shows a default undo button. But in my case I have disabled the same as I need a custom Undo and Redo button to do the same. But I am not sure how I can do that. Can anyone please help me with this?

My theory:
On polygon complete I set events insert_at, set_at and click in which I set the edits array so that I can keep track of all the edits.
Once the undo button is clicked I pop last element out of the edits array and add it to redo array and set the polygon path to popped element's path. To make this clear below is the code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    myArea = polygon;
    myArea.setOptions({ editable: true});
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', function(ind) {

        edits_arr.push(polygon);            
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(ind) {

        edits_arr.push(polygon);    
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(e) {
        polygon.getPath().removeAt(e.vertex);
        edits_arr.push(polygon);    
    });

});
```

Undo click:

```
$('#undo').click(function(){
    if(edits_arr.length > 0){
        var temp = edits_arr.pop();
        redo_arr.push(temp);
        var pathArrayTemp = temp.getPath();
        myArea.setMap(null); 
        myArea.setPaths(pathArrayTemp);
        myArea.setMap(map);

    }   
});
```

But all this doesn't seem to work. I know I am missing something here but can't figure out what.. :(

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

you must clone path for redo_arr

in your's redo_arr many links for one object